# Trying to find regression & p-value for every row of a csv file in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, anova

Hi I'm fairly new to R and am having some trouble with trying to do linear regression per row.

I can't attach the actual dataset because I'm not allowed to share it but this is the basic outline:

```
       Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec (...total 12 cols)              
Type 1
Type 2 
Type 3 
(... total 1680 rows)

The values are level of inventory for each type, numeric (no strings).
```

Basically what I want to do is [outlined here](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/business-statistics/how-to-estimate-a-trend-in-a-time-series-regression-model/):

(1) Linear Regression with time as independent variable

(2) ANOVA Test to see if coefficient of time is statistically significant.

What I want to do is regression analysis for every row (i.e. for every "type"), with time as the independent variable and then output a p-value for each row which will be added to the row in a new column. The purpose is to use p-value to see if there's trends in inventory for each individual type without having to graph 1680 different types of product, because that would be very hard to analyse.

I've looked through a lot of similar questions using lm() for each row but none that include how I would go about outputting a p-value instead of the coefficients themselves. Hope someone can help!

Comment: You may have better results posting on the Cross-validated stack exchange.

Comment: probably the easiest way to do this is to "melt" the data set (i.e,, convert to long form), then apply one of the many "linear regression by groups" solutions on SO (e.g. `nlme::lmList()`)

Comment: What do you mean by your p-value? In a linear regression a p-value is used to determine whether a variable contributes to the model. It is not used to determine whether the model has a trend, whether it is accurate, whether it meets all of the assumptions for linear regression, whether it will be valid beyond 12 data points, etc.

Comment: Also, 12 data points is very small. And you really only have 1 [ordered] variable which is the month. In time series analysis you'll be able to tell whether there is a slope (trend) but not a whole lot more. You could probably also tell whether the data is convex or concave, or some other sort of metric. But if there is yearly seasonality then you're not going to get much out of a linear regression of 12 months.

Comment: What I mean is in this case the regression is being used to find the coefficient of time, and I'm trying to see if the coefficient of time is statistically significant as an indicator of whether there is a trend. For my purposes, I only need to find out whether  (a) there is a trend, time series is not stationary or (b) no trend, stationary time series. What I hope to identify is any stagnant inventory. Using p-value or adf.test seems most intuitive since I can't very well have 1680 different graphs and identify stagnant types that way.

Comment: Btw referring to above comment, currently am also trying adf.test as an alternative, but regression seems simpler

Answer (score 0):

The comments are useful ie in terms of model validity please refer to Cross-validated. Here is how I'd approach the code with `data.table` package:

```
# some fake value
input <- data.frame(type=1:3, x1=rnorm(3), x2=rnorm(3), x3=rnorm(3), x4=rnorm(3))

# package for data manipulating, run install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

# convert to data.table and set names based on time index
input_dt <- as.data.table(input)
setnames(input_dt, c("type", 1:(ncol(input_dt)-1)))
input_dt[]

# wide to long format for modelling
dt <- melt(input_dt, id.vars = "type", variable.name="time")
dt[, time := as.numeric(time)]

# function to fit lm and get p-value
# replace with yours
myPvalFun <- function(data){

  # model. Do value ~ -1 + time for no intercept model
  mod <- lm(value ~ time, data=data)

  # p-values for regressor
  pvals <- summary(mod)$coefficients[,4]

  # just time p-value, [1] is intercept
  return(pvals[2])
}

# loop across using lapply and splitting the data up
pvals_list <- lapply(unique(dt$type), function(i){
  mod_dt <- dt[type==i,]
  data.table(type=i, pval=myPvalFun(mod_dt))
})
# bind list to a data.table
pvals <- rbindlist(pvals_list)

# make output and convert to data.frame
output_dt <- merge(input_dt, pvals, by="type")
output <- as.data.frame(output_dt)
```

Comment: Could you explain    " input <- data.frame(type=1:3, x1=rnorm(3), x2=rnorm(3), x3=rnorm(3), x4=rnorm(3))", in this case what are you assigning to be x1,x2,x3,x4 and why rnorm?

Comment: That's just my sample data. It would be replaced with your data. I used `rnorm` to make some dummy values so that the code can be ran and evaluated

Comment: Ah I understand, so in this case I will have to convert my csv to a data.frame format, I assume?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this code and let you know but looks pretty solid!

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention my first 3 columns are other details about each "type", they're string and need to be ignored. how can I add a command to ignore those columns when doing the regression?