# Fitting a regression model row-wise

Tags: r, regression, lm

I have data which is consist of information like this

```
dput(a)
structure(list(ENSEMBL = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("ENSG00000005187", 
"ENSG00000006740", "ENSG00000008277", "ENSG00000013810"), class = "factor"), 
    log2FoldChange_Expression = c(-2.2756549273843, -1.76655532051033, 
    -1.58489726654531, -1.58489726654531, -1.58489726654531, 
    -2.04282868170093), log2FoldChange_Region = c(-2.11261476936419, 
    -2.37119008459253, -1.59565539803813, -2.4954310786834, -2.11050911441613, 
    -1.81996408306615), Peak_Region = structure(c(5L, 6L, 4L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Peak147010", "Peak194531", "Peak194535", 
    "Peak194536", "Peak75759", "Peak81940"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

The dataframe small subset

```
a
          ENSEMBL log2FoldChange_Expression log2FoldChange_Region Peak_Region
1 ENSG00000005187                 -2.275655             -2.112615   Peak75759
2 ENSG00000006740                 -1.766555             -2.371190   Peak81940
3 ENSG00000008277                 -1.584897             -1.595655  Peak194536
4 ENSG00000008277                 -1.584897             -2.495431  Peak194531
5 ENSG00000008277                 -1.584897             -2.110509  Peak194535
6 ENSG00000013810                 -2.042829             -1.819964  Peak147010
```

My objective is to fit a regression model where I would like see

my `log2FoldChange_Expression` my `response variable` and `log2FoldChange_Region` is my `independent variable`

Now the basic lm which i know how to run is this

```
res=lm(log2FoldChange_Expression ~ log2FoldChange_Region, data=Down_data)
```

My objective is to see which im not sure if it is logical or not!.

1. For `Peak_Region` and its respective `ENSEMBL`I want to fit that model and see pvalue for each row. Is it possible to do the same?

I want to have final output table where I would like to see pvalue for each row

```
ENSEMBL log2FoldChange_Expression log2FoldChange_Region Peak_Region           pvalue 
1 ENSG00000005187                 -2.275655             -2.112615   Peak75759
2 ENSG00000006740                 -1.766555             -2.371190   Peak81940
3 ENSG00000008277                 -1.584897             -1.595655  Peak194536
4 ENSG00000008277                 -1.584897             -2.495431  Peak194531
5 ENSG00000008277                 -1.584897             -2.110509  Peak194535
6 ENSG00000013810                 -2.042829             -1.819964  Peak147010
```

Comment: This does not make sense. You cannot fit a linear model on one data point. Or rather you can (maybe) but you won't be able to estimate anything else except for the coefficient (which is equal to a regular average), so no p-values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59053695/trying-to-find-regression-p-value-for-every-row-of-a-csv-file-in-r this was one example i did see

Comment: my objective to is to filter some key genes so would simple correlation would be suffice ? like high or low correlation

Comment: @user2974951 "This does not make sense. You cannot fit a linear model on one data point." if i define them into different groups would that be possible?

Comment: @PesKchan, I assume that your data set is much bigger. How many unique (distinct) values do you have in Peak_Region? You can create a new categorical variable, where you create a few values based on the grouping of Peak_Region. Then just insert it as a independable variable next to existing "log2FoldChange_Region".

Comment: " I assume that your data set is much bigger. " yes it runs into few thousand rows, The peak values are unique but the corresponding genes are not unique since 2 different peak can annotate to the same gene

Comment: " You can create a new categorical variable, where you create a few values based on the grouping of Peak_Region." can you just give me a dummy R translation for this?

Comment: @Bloxx here is one solution https://community.rstudio.com/t/linear-regression-by-rows/21452

Comment: This example is not similar to yours. They have 4 values for each item to evaluate whether it is a positive trend or negative. You aim to evaluate each "item" based on 1 value. You can, for example, perform your analysis on all data points, and then check how the estimate differed for each ENSEMBL. I will post it as an answer, BUT I don't think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: My simple idea is whether a change  ENSEMBL ID and its respective log2 value is associated with its each Peak region ID. The objective is to i have to narrow down to list of ENSEMBLE ID which would go for downstream analysis so here in both the value are negative i want to find those hits which are strongly correlated like "log2FoldChange_Expression  and log2FoldChange_Region Peak_Region" both  should have strong association Im not sure regressing is the right concept here or other ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at my last comment.

```
Down_data <- structure(list(ENSEMBL = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L),
                                         .Label = c("ENSG00000005187","ENSG00000006740", "ENSG00000008277", "ENSG00000013810"),
                                         class = "factor"),
                     log2FoldChange_Expression = c(-2.2756549273843, -1.76655532051033,-1.58489726654531, -1.58489726654531, -1.58489726654531,-2.04282868170093),
                     log2FoldChange_Region = c(-2.11261476936419,-2.37119008459253, -1.59565539803813, -2.4954310786834, -2.11050911441613,-1.81996408306615),
                     Peak_Region = structure(c(5L, 6L, 4L,2L, 3L, 1L),
                                             .Label = c("Peak147010", "Peak194531", "Peak194535","Peak194536", "Peak75759", "Peak81940"),
                                             class = "factor")),
                class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA,-6L))

res=lm(log2FoldChange_Expression ~ log2FoldChange_Region + ENSEMBL, data=Down_data)
summary(res)
```

Comment: res=lm(log2FoldChange_Expression ~ log2FoldChange_Region + Peak_Region, data=Down_data)
Im curious why this doesn;t work?